# PrimeNG table expand fire all row components

Tags: angular, angular5, primeng

I'm have a problem with `p-table` component, when I'm clickinkg expand button, all row components are fired once again, so all request goes one again.
It's my configuration:

```
  <p-table [value]="cars" dataKey="number"
       [responsive]="true" rowExpandMode="single"
       [loading]="loading" sortMode="multiple">
```

Do you know how to disable components refreshing in expaneded column ? I'm write `console.log` in `ngOnInit`, and every component is intialize every time when I click expand btn.

Answer (score 2):

If in data table same value will be there and want to expand single row then dataKey should be unique.
[dataKey]="uniqueId"

its working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the table a `[dataKey]="uniqueId"`